# Browsing UNC Paths with a Mobile Emulator/Device

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

What would cause an emulator unable to view the network UNC shares? When attempting to open any computer on the network via 'Open Path' or Internet Explorer, I am tossed "The network path was not found." followed by "Network resource cannot be found or you do not have permission to access the network." Things to note:

- Connecting to the IP address does not work.
- I am able to browse the internet via the emulator.
- ActiveSync has been configured appropriately and I have installed the needed drivers for the adapter, and the emulator is cradled.
- Firewall disabled/setup with correct forwardings.
- Network folder permissions are setup properly.

What strikes me as odd is I have also attempted to browse UNC shares on a physical Windows Mobile 5 device, with the same issue. This leads me to believe something within our network settings is causing this but I'm not sure where to start. People have recommended checking ActiveDirectory security policies, but what policies affect UNC shares? This has turned into a rather serious issue because until I am able to resolve this, I am unable to go through with setting up merge replication. Has anyone experienced this and successfully resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your network is looking for authentication.

I get that here at my work place, too.

As long as your network key is entered correctly, you should be able to try browsing to that same path 2 or 3 more times, still getting those same obnoxious (*"The network path was not found." followed by "Network resource cannot be found or you do not have permission to access the network."*) messages.

At one of those times, a login box should appear where you type in a Username, Password, and Domain.

You will also have the ability at this point to save your password so you are not prompted for it every time you attempt to access something across your network.

Now here's the real crapper: After you save your Username/Password combination, there does not appear to be any mechanism within the Windows Mobile device to change that password after it expires on your network. You will never be prompted again to change that password, either. You will only get one of those silly messages above because your password is incorrect.

The only solution to this seems to be to reset the device. I have had a question open with Microsoft for about 3 years now, and it has been passed from one forum to another. I've finally just decided that it must not be able to be done, but Microsoft has never written back to tell me that.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Unfortunately, I am never prompted with a login box and I have tried countless times to attempt to open the path. I have reset the device twice already as well, and even within the emulator I am not prompted with any sort of authentication prompt. What methods have you tried to see this prompt?

Comment: From **File Explorer**, click **Menu** (lower right), **Open Path >**, **New Path...**, enter the network path (like `\\server1\Shared Folders\jp2code`), and click **OK**. I typically get your error once or twice on a new device. If I can not connect, I go back to checking the wireless settings (encryption, key, etc.).

Comment: I'm actually connected via the cradle so wireless authentication wouldn't be the issue.